# Mover archivos a la papelera con Python

Tags: python

Me gustaria saber si es posible mover los archivos que ya no utilizo desde la carpeta de descargas por ejemplo hacia la papelera, con python.

Mover seria con `shutil.move` pero no encuentro la ruta para la papelera. (si hay una forma mejor, estaria encantado de escucharla)

La otra pregunta que tengo es, se puede mover todos los archivos con un `for` o necesito eliminarlos 1 a 1?

Muchas gracias !

```
import os, shutil


contenido_descargas = os.listdir("C:/Users/reysp/Downloads/")

for elemento in contenido_descargas:
    print('Ficheros: ' + elemento)

ruta_original = ('C:/Users/reysp/Downloads/Prueba')
ruta_papelera = ('')


shutil.move(ruta_original, ruta_papelera)
```

Comment: Se que no es la mejor solución, pero si ninguno de nosotros haya/sabe como mover archivos a la papelera, entonces podrías crear una carpeta con los archivos "eliminados" y usarla como si fuera la papelera de reciclaje. Para vaciarla, puedes hacer otro programa que borre todos los archivos de dicha carpeta.

Comment: Esto responde a tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628517/how-can-i-move-file-into-recycle-bin-trash-on-different-platforms-using-pyqt4

Comment: Gracias, intentare esa opcion de momento. Muchas gracias de nuevo !

Comment: De nada Danii c:

Answer (score 2):

Por el código que muestras supongo que estás trabajando en Windows.
Si te restringes a ese sistema operativo puedes usar el módulo [`winshell`](https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
Usa la función [`delete_file`](https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file-operations.html#winshell.delete_file), cuyo argumento `allow_undo` por defecto es `True` lo cual enviará el archivo a la papelera.

```
import winshell
winshell.delete_file(file_path)
```

Si quieres una versión que se pueda usar en varios sistemas operativos, puedes usar la librería: [`send2trash`](https://github.com/arsenetar/send2trash). La puedes instalar con `pip install Send2Trash`.
Para usarla:

```
from send2trash import send2trash
send2trash(file_path)
```

Si lees la documentación verás que las dos librerías pueden tomar o bien un archivo de manera individual o una lista con las rutas de los archivos que deseas enviar a la papelera.